# Selenium WebDriver Java: Change DOM before DOMContentLoaded

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageloadstrategy

My aim is to change the DOM of a page before the DOMContentLoaded event. Let's say my JS would look like the code below and I want to change a value of an element:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("Value of element foo: " + document.getElementById('foo').value);
});
```

I know to change the DOM with the `JavascriptExecutor` of Selenium WebDriver, but I'm missing how to get it to to execute right before 'DOMContentLoaded' (and maybe that's not the right approach).

```
// some hook or whatever to execute right before 'DOMContentLoaded' or wherever suitable
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("document.getElementById('foo').value='hi there'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that you will have to set the [`pageLoadStrategy`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/shared/) from default `normal` to `none`.
This will pass the control to the next code line immediately after launching the page with `driver.get()` method without waiting for the page content to be loaded.

Comment: Seems like the only way to achieve this. One more question: Wouldn't I be in competition with the the eventListener of the calling page, since I would have to also wrap my DOM changing task in an eventListener:
`((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.addEventListener(\"DOMContentLoaded\", function(event) { document.getElementById('foo').value='hi there'; });");`

Comment: As about the additional question - I really do not know, I'm sorry. I would help you if I could but I don't know... You are welcome to ask a new question about that, maybe someone will be able to help there.